# Python: Hash of pdf file vs downloaded object

Tags: python, pdf, hash

I want to check if the content of a pdf on a webserver is identical with the content of a pdf on my computer. I tried this without success:

```
>>> import requests, hashlib
>>> pdf = requests.get('<http link to pdf file>')
>>> type(pdf.content)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> type(repr(open('file.pdf','rb')).encode('utf-8'))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> hashlib.sha256(repr(open('file.pdf','rb')).encode('utf-8')) == hashlib.sha256(repr(pdf.content).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
False
>>> hashlib.sha256(repr(open('file.pdf','rb')).encode('utf-8')) == hashlib.sha256(pdf.content).hexdigest()
False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re hashing the UTF-8-encoded `repr` of the file object, not the file’s contents. There’s no reason to use `repr` anyway; hash the contents directly.

```
>>> with open('file.pdf', 'rb') as f:
...     h1 = hashlib.sha256(f.read()).digest()
>>> h2 = hashlib.sha256(pdf.content).digest()
>>> h1 == h2
True
```

Answer (score 3):

the first hash is the hash of the representation of a file object (and not its contents):

```
repr(open('file.pdf','rb'))  
    # "<_io.BufferedReader name='file.pdf'>"
repr(open('file.pdf','rb')).encode('utf-8')  
    # b"<_io.BufferedReader name='file.pdf'>"
```

your first hash is over the `bytes`: `b"<_io.BufferedReader name='file.pdf'>"`.